# Topological hyperfields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra

I am trying to generalize the notion of reorientation class of an oriented matroid to the context of matroids over hyperfields (compare [Baker and Bowler, 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01204)). I have already got some results in this direction. Particularly, given a hyperfield $\mathbb{H}$ and a matroid $M$ I am able to combinatorially and algebraically characterize the "moduli space" of all "reorientation" classes of $\mathbb{H}$-matroids having $M$ as underlying matroid.

It would be nice to extend these statements to the setting of "topological" hyperfields, improving on some results on phased matroids (compare [Delucchi and S., 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.07109)). However, I do not know a proper definition of these objects.

**Question:** Is there any definition of topological hyperfield? In that case, can you kindly provide some reference in the literature?

Thank you very much for any kind of comments or suggestions.